# Execute command in linked docker container

Tags: docker

Is there any way posible to exec command from inside one docker container in the linked docker container? 
I don't want to exec command from the host.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690421/10534470

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have access to something like the docker socket within your container, you can run any command inside any docker container, doesn't matter whether or not it is linked. For example:

```
# run a container and link it to `other`
docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           --link other:other myimage bash -l
bash$ docker exec --it other echo hello
```

This works even if the link was not specified.

Comment: Doing this allows anything running in the container to take control of the host machine.

Comment: @ChrisPitman yeah, obviously containers are just like any other binaries, don't run something you don't trust. I don't think that's relevant in any way.

Comment: There is a difference between "be careful about what you run" and "we implemented a trivial container escape vulnerability". This is equivalent to allowing users anonymous ssh to your servers because no one unauthorized should have access to your network.

Comment: This is a common practice, it's even endorsed by docker engineers: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/07/12/10-docker-tips-and-tricks-that-will-make-you-sing-a-whale-song-of-joy/

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. By mounting a docker socket on a container, a container will immediately see all exposed ports from other containers (the same as host does), which is not ideal for things like dockerize and wait-for-it since you loose the ability to wait for the ports to get "ready".

Answer (score 1):

With **docker-compose**:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  site:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: test-site
    command: sleep 999999

  dkr:
    image: docker
    privileged: true
    working_dir: "/dkr"
    volumes:
      - ".:/dkr"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    command: docker ps -a
```

Then try:

```
docker-compose up -d site
docker-compose up dkr
```

result:

```
Attaching to tmp_dkr_1
dkr_1   | CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS                   PORTS                     NAMES
dkr_1   | 25e382142b2e        docker                            "docker-entrypoint..."   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second                              tmp_dkr_1
```

### Example Project

https://github.com/reduardo7/docker-container-access

Answer (score 0):

As "Abdullah Jibaly" said you can do that but there is some security issues you have to consider, also there is [sdk docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) to use, and for python applications can use [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)