# Docker : Can a container A call an executable located on an other container B?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pandoc, pdflatex

I have two Docker images, one containing [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/) (an utility to convert documents in different formats to many formats), and an other containing `pdflatex` (from [`texlive`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), to convert `tex` files into `pdf`). My goal here is to convert documents from `md` to `pdf`.

I can run each image separately :

```
# call pandoc inside my-pandoc-image (md -> tex)
docker run --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/pandoc \
    my-pandoc-image \
    pandoc -s test.md -o test.tex

# call pdflatex inside my-texlive-image (tex -> pdf)
docker run --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/texlive \
    my-texlive-image \
    pdflatex test.tex # generates test.pdf
```

But, in fact, what I want is to call `pandoc` (from its container) directly to convert `md` into `pdf`, like this :

```
docker run --rm \
    -v $(pwd):/pandoc \
    my-pandoc-image \
    pandoc -s test.md --latex-engine pdflatex -o test.pdf
```

This command does not work here, because `pandoc` inside the container tries to call `pdflatex` (that must be in `$PATH`) to generate the pdf, but `pdflatex` does not exist since it is not installed in the `my-pandoc-image`.

In my case, `pdflatex` is installed in the image `my-texlive-image`.

So, from this example, my question is : Can a container A call an executable located on an other container B ?

I am pretty sure this is possible, because if I install `pandoc` **on my host** (without `pdflatex`), I can run `pandoc -s test.md--latex-engine=pdflatex -o test.pdf` by simply aliasing the `pdflatex` command with :

```
pdflatex() {
    docker run --rm \
        -v $(pwd):/texlive \
        my-texlive-image \
        pdflatex "$@"
}
```

Thus, when `pdflatex` is called by `pandoc`, a container starts and do the conversion.

But when using the 2 containers, how could I alias the `pdflatex` command to simulate its existence on the container having only `pandoc` ?

I took a look at `docker-compose`, since I have already used it to make 2 containers communicate (app communicating with a database). I even thought about `ssh`-ing from container A to container B to call the `pdflatex` command, but this is definitively [not the right solution](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/).

Finally, I also have built an image containing `pandoc` + `pdflatex` (it worked because the two executables were on the same image), but I really want to keep the 2 images separately, since they could be used independently by other images.

#### Edit :

A similar question is exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907979/execute-command-in-linked-docker-container), as I understand the provided answer needs Docker to be installed on container A, and needs a docker socket binding (`/var/run/docker.sock`) between host and container A. I don't think this is best practice, it seems like a hack that can create [security issues](https://raesene.github.io/blog/2016/03/06/The-Dangers-Of-Docker.sock/).

Comment: Not directly, but you could do a ssh connection from the container to the another container host, with a docker exec command.

Comment: If I understand well, I need to install a ssh server on container B + a ssh client on container A ? It seems to be not a best practice from what I read (https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/). Maybe my architecture with 2 separate containers is wrong ?

Comment: You have to expose some kind of service from pdflatex so that other docker container can use that service.Service can be anything (rest api call,...).That way both container are independent and can run in any machine,too.

Comment: @GirdharSojitra I took a look at CLSI (https://github.com/sharelatex/clsi-sharelatex), a web API to compile LaTeX, but it seems overkill to install it in a container for my needs. More generally (if such API does not exist), I'd like to know what is the right way to call a command on another container (for other use-cases).

Comment: The specific use-case of pandoc and LaTeX is probably best handled by using the official [pandoc/latex](https://github.com/pandoc/dockerfiles) images.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to your problem, I'll let you choose the one that suits you best. They are presented below, from the cleanest to the ugliest (in my opinion and regarding the best practices generally followed).

## 1. Make it a service

If you end up calling it often, **it may be worth exposing pandoc as an (HTTP) API**. Some images already do that, for example [metal3d/pandoc-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/metal3d/pandoc-server/) (which I already used with success, but I'm sure you can find others).

In this case, you just run a container with `pandoc` + `pdflatex` **once** and you're set!

## 2. Use image inheritance!

Make 2 images : one with `pandoc` only, and the other one with `pandoc` + `pdflatex`, **inheriting the first one with the `FROM` directive in the `Dockerfile`**.

It will solve your concerns about size and still being able to run pandoc without having to fetch `pdflatex` too. Then if you need to pull the image with `pdflatex`, it will just be **an extra layer**, not the entire image.

You can also do it the other way, with a base image `pdflatex` and another adding `pandoc` to it if you find yourself using the `pdflatex` image alone  often and rarely using the `pandoc` image without `pdflatex`. You could also make 3 images, `pandoc`, `pdflatex`, and `pdflatex + pandoc`, to cover every need you might have, but then you'll have at least one image that isn't linked in any way to the 2 others (can't heritate a "child" image), making it a bit harder to maintain.

## 3. Docker client in `my-pandoc-image` + Docker socket mount

This is the solution that you mentionned at the end of your post, and which is probably the most **generic and straightforward solution** for calling other containerized commands, not taking your precise usecase of `pandoc` + `pdflatex` into account.

Just add the docker client to your image `my-pandoc-image` and pass the Docker socket as volume at runtime using `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. And if you're concerned is not being able to make `pandoc` call `docker run ...` instead of `pdflatex` directly, just add a poor wrapper called `pdflatex` in `/usr/local/bin/` which will be responsible of doing the `docker run`

## 4. Use volumes-from to get the binary

This one is probably the **less clean** I'll present here. You could try getting either the `pandoc` binary in a `pdflatex` container or the `pdflatex` binary in a `pandoc` container using `--volumes-from` to keep everything packaged in its own Docker image. But honnestly, it's more of a duct tape than a real solution.

## Conclusion

You can chose the solution that best fits your needs, but I would advise the first 2 and strongly discourage the last one.

Comment: Great explanation ! Finally I'm going to choose solution 2 (with 2 images : `pandoc` and `pandoc + pdflatex`), since it is the easiest and the most adapted to my needs. Thanks ;)

Comment: Where can I find more detailed info about solution 3?