# How I can call command's container B inside my container A in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm configuring two docker containers, container A and container B. Is it possible to call a command of B inside A, using any configuration like network or link or some other?

I tried with network and link but I didn't have success.

This configuration I would like to do for separate a container that will use a lot of CPU from the other.

I expected call a B container inside container A in a transparently way, and up other new "B"s containers when necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker : Can a container A call an executable located on an other container B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442276/docker-can-a-container-a-call-an-executable-located-on-an-other-container-b)

Comment: In short: no, you can't, not without putting a proper network interface between them.  The only answer to that question lists out most of the options.